# req.user is undefined even though it is able to console.log the user

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jwt, schema, graphql

I am trying to implement authentication in Graphql using JWT. I have a function that is supposed the grab the user information given a token. It should return the user so that I can use it in my Graphql queries.

When I try to make a post request it comes back as null.

```
const addUser = async (req) => {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    try {
      const { user } = await jwt.verify(token, SECRET);
      req.user = user;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    req.next();
  };


app.use(addUser);
```

```
app.use("/graphql", graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: {
        user: req.user,
        SECRET
    }
}))
```

The console is saying that 
 user: req.user,

ReferenceError: req is not defined

I don't understand why, because I have already set req.user equal to the user

Comment: Regardless of what you may have done in the 1st piece of code, the second one doesn't know what `req` is.

Comment: So how can I make it so that the second function knows what req.user is

Comment: Check the example at the end of this: https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#options

Comment: I read it and I see the example but how would I implement this in my code

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how to answer that. This website isn't a place to get free step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: Yea I tried returning it but that didn’t work either. I guess just keep trying different stuff

Comment: Put code you tried in the question so we can take a look and help fix it.

Comment: I just put return in front of req.user = user but that didn’t work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use `express-graphql`, take a look about the doc: https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql

You use `graphqlHTTP` middleware in the wrong way.

Take a look below code:

```js
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP(async (request, response, graphQLParams) => ({
  schema: MyGraphQLSchema,
  rootValue: await someFunctionToGetRootValue(request),
  graphiql: true
})));
```

You should pass function with the `req` parameter into the `graphqlHTTP` middleware.